# Reducing image size in javascript without reducing the picture quality and download the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi friends i am reduce the image using javascript but losing its quality. Please help me for same picture quality with reduce the image size. The below is my code please help me.

I am upload a image using input file. for multiple file also you have to upload while uploading the images, the images are reduce the size but quality is lossing so please help me... I am suffering from this problem from 2 days...

**html code**

```
<div class="row">
        <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" />
        <output id="filesInfo"></output>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script>

    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        document.getElementById('filesToUpload').onchange = function () {
            var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
            }
        };
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    function resizeAndUpload(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {

            var tempImg = new Image();
            tempImg.src = reader.result;
            tempImg.onload = function () {

                var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
                var tempW = tempImg.width;
                var tempH = tempImg.height;
                if (tempW > tempH) {
                    if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                        tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                        tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = tempW;
                canvas.height = tempH;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = '<img  src="' + dataURL + '" />';

                document.getElementById('filesInfo').appendChild(div);
            }

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if you reduce the image size you will necessarily reduce the image quality. You can try to add `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false` to avoid the blurred aspect. Also keep in mind that `ctx.toDataUrl()` returns the image as base64 encoded, which result in data about 30% larger than the jpeg bytes array for the same image size.

Comment: Can you add an example of "before" and "after" image? I don't quite understand, what do you mean by "quality". Also, you may try to use `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` to get rid of jpeg compression and its quality losses.

Comment: If i upload the images but the image size is more then 2 mb reduce the size. and the saved image is display in our website by default no problem, but if i click on the image the image is zoom at that time the image quality is necessary so that why i am asking.... please help me....

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do that that keep the same dimensions of the image while doing a better job at compressing without sacrificing visual quality. I've been looking into the subject as well - there's a couple of companys that are providing commercial (and server-side) solutions for it, such as kraken.io or jpegmini.com. The results are 60% smaller file sizes but look almost the same.

Natually, they don't describe what they are doing, but I would assume that they're going very much to the internals of the jpeg compression to archieve these results.

If you want to make any progress in that field, this will probably require you to deeply understand the jpeg compression algorithm and not rely on the standard javascript jpeg compression library.